# Azure DevOps variable group. Scope - release vs stage

Tags: azure-devops

im using a variable group in azdo classic pipelines. When I link my variable group to scope `release` I get a 401 unauthorized error but when I scope my variable group to specific stages in that release it works properly. Im confused on why that is. Any info on this would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Please explain *where* you get a 401 error. During the pipeline run? At what point? What step is running? What variable is it trying to resolve? You need to provide a lot more detail if you want help.

Comment: this issue was due to variables in the variable group being secrets. If you need to get around this issue created a key vault reference or specifically scope the variable group to independent stages

Answer (score 0):

this issue was due to variables in the variable group being secrets. If you need to get around this issue created a key vault reference or specifically scope the variable group to independent stages